# combining and working with multiple JSON files

Tags: r, json

I'm very new to working with JSON files and am really struggling. The software I'm working with outputs 1 JSON file for each image it processes. At any one time I'm ending up with 100's of individual JSON files. The main issues I'm having at the moment is that I don't know how to get everything into one cohesive, workable file in R. So far I have done this:

```
# character vector with each file name represented by an entry
filenames <- list.files("~/JSON_output/", pattern="*.json", full.names=TRUE)

# a list in which each element is one of the original JSON files
myJSON <- lapply(filenames, function(x) rjson::fromJSON(file = x)) 

# investigate the structure of the list
str(myJSON, max.level = 1, list.len = 10)
```

So far so good. The files all seem to be in there, but the element `lithic_contours` contains a `data.frame`.

If I was working with an individual image I can easily access this with

```
# Subset the list on lithic_contours with $ ...
df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(<file>, flatten = TRUE)$lithic_contours

# ... and it's already a data.frame
class(df)
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

However, I am unable to do this with the entire collection of images (myJON from above). I'm at a loss as how to get this data set together into a workable data frame. Any help would be appreciated. I've included 3 JSON files below. Thank you for any help.

```
{
  "id": "rub_al_khali",
  "conversion_px": 0.0395882818685669,
  "n_surfaces": 4,
  "lithic_contours": [
    {
      "surface_id": 0,
      "classification": "Ventral",
      "total_area_px": 530565.5,
      "total_area": 831.5,
      "max_breadth": 22.4,
      "max_length": 54,
      "polygon_count": 7,
      "scar_count": 0,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0,
      "scar_contours": []
    },
    {
      "surface_id": 1,
      "classification": "Dorsal",
      "total_area_px": 530503.5,
      "total_area": 831.4,
      "max_breadth": 22.4,
      "max_length": 54,
      "polygon_count": 7,
      "scar_count": 4,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0.62,
      "scar_contours": [
        {
          "scar_id": 0,
          "total_area_px": 129337,
          "total_area": 202.7,
          "max_breadth": 10.3,
          "max_length": 41.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.24,
          "scar_angle": 1.85,
          "polygon_count": 5
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 1,
          "total_area_px": 100130,
          "total_area": 156.9,
          "max_breadth": 7.2,
          "max_length": 43,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.19,
          "scar_angle": 357.36,
          "polygon_count": 4
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 2,
          "total_area_px": 93162,
          "total_area": 146,
          "max_breadth": 6.5,
          "max_length": 41.4,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.18,
          "scar_angle": 5.01,
          "polygon_count": 4
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 3,
          "total_area_px": 6148.5,
          "total_area": 9.6,
          "max_breadth": 4,
          "max_length": 7.1,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 9
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "surface_id": 2,
      "classification": "Lateral",
      "total_area_px": 176204,
      "total_area": 276.2,
      "max_breadth": 8.6,
      "max_length": 54.2,
      "polygon_count": 3,
      "scar_count": 2,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0.33,
      "scar_contours": [
        {
          "scar_id": 0,
          "total_area_px": 44605,
          "total_area": 69.9,
          "max_breadth": 5,
          "max_length": 50,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.25,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 3
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 1,
          "total_area_px": 12877,
          "total_area": 20.2,
          "max_breadth": 1.5,
          "max_length": 22.3,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.07,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "surface_id": 3,
      "classification": "Platform",
      "total_area_px": 55252.5,
      "total_area": 86.6,
      "max_breadth": 20.3,
      "max_length": 6.6,
      "polygon_count": 5,
      "scar_count": 1,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0.42,
      "scar_contours": [
        {
          "scar_id": 0,
          "total_area_px": 23298.5,
          "total_area": 36.5,
          "max_breadth": 15,
          "max_length": 4.1,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.42,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

{
  "id": "160",
  "conversion_px": 0.06443298969072166,
  "n_surfaces": 3,
  "lithic_contours": [
    {
      "surface_id": 0,
      "classification": "Dorsal",
      "total_area_px": 147674,
      "total_area": 613.1,
      "max_breadth": 21.5,
      "max_length": 36.1,
      "polygon_count": 5,
      "scar_count": 10,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0.81,
      "scar_contours": [
        {
          "scar_id": 0,
          "total_area_px": 37128,
          "total_area": 154.1,
          "max_breadth": 10.1,
          "max_length": 26.4,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.25,
          "scar_angle": 169.05,
          "polygon_count": 9
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 1,
          "total_area_px": 25267.5,
          "total_area": 104.9,
          "max_breadth": 6.6,
          "max_length": 24.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.17,
          "scar_angle": 343.61,
          "polygon_count": 6
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 2,
          "total_area_px": 19178.5,
          "total_area": 79.6,
          "max_breadth": 5.2,
          "max_length": 21.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.13,
          "scar_angle": 0,
          "polygon_count": 5
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 3,
          "total_area_px": 17053,
          "total_area": 70.8,
          "max_breadth": 6.1,
          "max_length": 15.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.12,
          "scar_angle": 3.3,
          "polygon_count": 7
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 4,
          "total_area_px": 5279.5,
          "total_area": 21.9,
          "max_breadth": 6.3,
          "max_length": 6.6,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.04,
          "scar_angle": 162.35,
          "polygon_count": 8
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 5,
          "total_area_px": 4290.5,
          "total_area": 17.8,
          "max_breadth": 5.2,
          "max_length": 9.8,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.03,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 5
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 6,
          "total_area_px": 4013,
          "total_area": 16.7,
          "max_breadth": 3.4,
          "max_length": 8.1,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.03,
          "scar_angle": 184.57,
          "polygon_count": 4
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 7,
          "total_area_px": 3166,
          "total_area": 13.1,
          "max_breadth": 3.1,
          "max_length": 6.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.02,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 6
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 8,
          "total_area_px": 2022,
          "total_area": 8.4,
          "max_breadth": 5.8,
          "max_length": 3.1,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 6
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 9,
          "total_area_px": 1569.5,
          "total_area": 6.5,
          "max_breadth": 6.7,
          "max_length": 2.3,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "surface_id": 1,
      "classification": "Lateral",
      "total_area_px": 117898,
      "total_area": 489.5,
      "max_breadth": 20.4,
      "max_length": 36.6,
      "polygon_count": 7,
      "scar_count": 8,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0.4,
      "scar_contours": [
        {
          "scar_id": 0,
          "total_area_px": 11067.5,
          "total_area": 45.9,
          "max_breadth": 7.5,
          "max_length": 10.5,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.09,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 5
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 1,
          "total_area_px": 9583,
          "total_area": 39.8,
          "max_breadth": 7.9,
          "max_length": 10.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.08,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 8
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 2,
          "total_area_px": 8745,
          "total_area": 36.3,
          "max_breadth": 18.2,
          "max_length": 7.2,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.07,
          "scar_angle": 96.34,
          "polygon_count": 6
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 3,
          "total_area_px": 7579.5,
          "total_area": 31.5,
          "max_breadth": 4.4,
          "max_length": 16.3,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.06,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 4
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 4,
          "total_area_px": 4452,
          "total_area": 18.5,
          "max_breadth": 4.8,
          "max_length": 8.2,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.04,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 10
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 5,
          "total_area_px": 2655.5,
          "total_area": 11,
          "max_breadth": 3.2,
          "max_length": 9,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.02,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 4
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 6,
          "total_area_px": 1492,
          "total_area": 6.2,
          "max_breadth": 2.5,
          "max_length": 4.5,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 5
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 7,
          "total_area_px": 1433.5,
          "total_area": 6,
          "max_breadth": 3.5,
          "max_length": 5.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "surface_id": 2,
      "classification": "Platform",
      "total_area_px": 63556,
      "total_area": 263.9,
      "max_breadth": 22.2,
      "max_length": 17.3,
      "polygon_count": 8,
      "scar_count": 0,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0,
      "scar_contours": []
    }
  ]
}

{
  "id": "194",
  "conversion_px": 0.12406947890818858,
  "n_surfaces": 3,
  "lithic_contours": [
    {
      "surface_id": 0,
      "classification": "Ventral",
      "total_area_px": 65777,
      "total_area": 1012.5,
      "max_breadth": 38.6,
      "max_length": 33.6,
      "polygon_count": 8,
      "scar_count": 8,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0.19,
      "scar_contours": [
        {
          "scar_id": 0,
          "total_area_px": 3408,
          "total_area": 52.5,
          "max_breadth": 8.7,
          "max_length": 9.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.05,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 7
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 1,
          "total_area_px": 3010,
          "total_area": 46.3,
          "max_breadth": 16.9,
          "max_length": 4.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.05,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 5
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 2,
          "total_area_px": 1530,
          "total_area": 23.6,
          "max_breadth": 3.8,
          "max_length": 10.9,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.02,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 10
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 3,
          "total_area_px": 1346.5,
          "total_area": 20.7,
          "max_breadth": 8.8,
          "max_length": 4.2,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.02,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 5
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 4,
          "total_area_px": 1001,
          "total_area": 15.4,
          "max_breadth": 7.2,
          "max_length": 4.3,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.02,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 7
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 5,
          "total_area_px": 884,
          "total_area": 13.6,
          "max_breadth": 5.5,
          "max_length": 6.5,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 7
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 6,
          "total_area_px": 844,
          "total_area": 13,
          "max_breadth": 3.6,
          "max_length": 5.3,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 7
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 7,
          "total_area_px": 674,
          "total_area": 10.4,
          "max_breadth": 5.3,
          "max_length": 4.2,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 8
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "surface_id": 1,
      "classification": "Dorsal",
      "total_area_px": 65223.5,
      "total_area": 1004,
      "max_breadth": 38.7,
      "max_length": 33.6,
      "polygon_count": 8,
      "scar_count": 13,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0.72,
      "scar_contours": [
        {
          "scar_id": 0,
          "total_area_px": 12230.5,
          "total_area": 188.3,
          "max_breadth": 17.7,
          "max_length": 16.9,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.19,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 9
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 1,
          "total_area_px": 6169,
          "total_area": 95,
          "max_breadth": 12.4,
          "max_length": 10.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.09,
          "scar_angle": 63.43,
          "polygon_count": 7
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 2,
          "total_area_px": 6132,
          "total_area": 94.4,
          "max_breadth": 13.6,
          "max_length": 12.5,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.09,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 13
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 3,
          "total_area_px": 5921,
          "total_area": 91.1,
          "max_breadth": 12.8,
          "max_length": 11.5,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.09,
          "scar_angle": 201.8,
          "polygon_count": 9
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 4,
          "total_area_px": 3866.5,
          "total_area": 59.5,
          "max_breadth": 7.6,
          "max_length": 12.9,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.06,
          "scar_angle": 160.35,
          "polygon_count": 9
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 5,
          "total_area_px": 3411.5,
          "total_area": 52.5,
          "max_breadth": 10.7,
          "max_length": 7.6,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.05,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 7
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 6,
          "total_area_px": 2272.5,
          "total_area": 35,
          "max_breadth": 5.5,
          "max_length": 9.8,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.03,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 8
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 7,
          "total_area_px": 2019.5,
          "total_area": 31.1,
          "max_breadth": 5.8,
          "max_length": 7.2,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.03,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 7
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 8,
          "total_area_px": 1684.5,
          "total_area": 25.9,
          "max_breadth": 9.8,
          "max_length": 8.8,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.03,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 9
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 9,
          "total_area_px": 862,
          "total_area": 13.3,
          "max_breadth": 3.3,
          "max_length": 6.5,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 5
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 10,
          "total_area_px": 827.5,
          "total_area": 12.7,
          "max_breadth": 6.3,
          "max_length": 4,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 5
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 11,
          "total_area_px": 787,
          "total_area": 12.1,
          "max_breadth": 4,
          "max_length": 4.8,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 6
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 12,
          "total_area_px": 699.5,
          "total_area": 10.8,
          "max_breadth": 4,
          "max_length": 4.2,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 6
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "surface_id": 2,
      "classification": "Lateral",
      "total_area_px": 15128,
      "total_area": 232.9,
      "max_breadth": 10,
      "max_length": 33.9,
      "polygon_count": 7,
      "scar_count": 5,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0.69,
      "scar_contours": [
        {
          "scar_id": 0,
          "total_area_px": 6122,
          "total_area": 94.2,
          "max_breadth": 6.5,
          "max_length": 28.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.4,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 7
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 1,
          "total_area_px": 1477,
          "total_area": 22.7,
          "max_breadth": 1.9,
          "max_length": 20.6,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.1,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 3
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 2,
          "total_area_px": 1415,
          "total_area": 21.8,
          "max_breadth": 3.1,
          "max_length": 13.6,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.09,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 5
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 3,
          "total_area_px": 800,
          "total_area": 12.3,
          "max_breadth": 4.5,
          "max_length": 6.6,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.05,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 7
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 4,
          "total_area_px": 596,
          "total_area": 9.2,
          "max_breadth": 2.1,
          "max_length": 9.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.04,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Okay, it contains a `data.frame` and you can look at it, but what do you want? Do you want each file's `lithic_contours` to be extracted (discarding all other elements of each json) and combined in a list? combined in a single much-longer frame? Your expectation is not clear.

Comment: @r2evans I want to be able to compare and analyse everything from all these individual JSON files. I don't want to eliminate anything. Every sapec of each JSON file is part of the analysis.

Comment: How about `alljson <- lapply(filenames, fromJSON)`, then `allcontours <- lapply(alljson, \`[[\`, "lithic_countirs")`.

Comment: @ r2evans. Thank you for your input, but this doesn't solve the issue. Your solution produces a list, and the ID for each JSON file is missing. I need a workable data frame that contains all this information. A tabular data set. In my example above I showed that df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(<file>, flatten = TRUE)$lithic_contours creates a data frame for a single JSON file. I need something like this for all the JSON files I'm working with, in one unified data frame that doesn't exlude information.

Answer (score 1):

I've saved your three json files as `file#.json` in the current directory. Let's first figure out how to read in *one* file into a single `data.frame`, and then we'll iterate over all of them.

First, helper functions. These make a couple of simple assumptions:

- within each `lithic_contours`, there are 0 or 1 `scar_contours` frame, and then all other values are length 1 (easily converted into a 1-row `data.frame`);
- within each json, there are 0 or more `lithic_contours` lists, and then all other values are length 1 (again, easily converted into a 1-row `data.frame`).

```r
each_lith <- function(onelith) {
  scar_contours <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, onelith$scar_contours)
  if (length(scar_contours)) names(scar_contours) <- paste0("scar_contour.", names(scar_contours))
  onelith$scar_contours <- NULL
  onelith <- as.data.frame(onelith)
  if (nrow(scar_contours)) {
    cbind(onelith, scar_contours, row.names = NULL)
  } else onelith
}
each_json <- function(onejson) {
  liths <- lapply(onejson$lithic_contours, each_lith)
  onejson$lithic_contours <- NULL
  onejson <- as.data.frame(onejson)
  cbind(onejson, data.table::rbindlist(liths, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE),
        row.names = NULL)
}
```

Working on one json:

```r
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "\\.json$", full.names = TRUE)
each_json(jsonlite::read_json(filenames[1]))
#             id conversion_px n_surfaces surface_id classification total_area_px total_area max_breadth max_length polygon_count scar_count percentage_detected_scars scar_contour.scar_id scar_contour.total_area_px scar_contour.total_area scar_contour.max_breadth scar_contour.max_length scar_contour.percentage_of_surface scar_contour.scar_angle scar_contour.polygon_count
# 1 rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          0        Ventral      530565.5      831.5        22.4       54.0             7          0                      0.00                   NA                         NA                      NA                       NA                      NA                                 NA                    <NA>                         NA
# 2 rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          1         Dorsal      530503.5      831.4        22.4       54.0             7          4                      0.62                    0                   129337.0                   202.7                     10.3                    41.7                               0.24                    1.85                          5
# 3 rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          1         Dorsal      530503.5      831.4        22.4       54.0             7          4                      0.62                    1                   100130.0                   156.9                      7.2                    43.0                               0.19                  357.36                          4
# 4 rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          1         Dorsal      530503.5      831.4        22.4       54.0             7          4                      0.62                    2                    93162.0                   146.0                      6.5                    41.4                               0.18                    5.01                          4
# 5 rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          1         Dorsal      530503.5      831.4        22.4       54.0             7          4                      0.62                    3                     6148.5                     9.6                      4.0                     7.1                               0.01                     NaN                          9
# 6 rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          2        Lateral      176204.0      276.2         8.6       54.2             3          2                      0.33                    0                    44605.0                    69.9                      5.0                    50.0                               0.25                     NaN                          3
# 7 rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          2        Lateral      176204.0      276.2         8.6       54.2             3          2                      0.33                    1                    12877.0                    20.2                      1.5                    22.3                               0.07                     NaN                          2
# 8 rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          3       Platform       55252.5       86.6        20.3        6.6             5          1                      0.42                    0                    23298.5                    36.5                     15.0                     4.1                               0.42                     NaN                          4
```

We can iterate fairly easily now,

```r
alljsons <- lapply(setNames(nm = filenames), jsonlite::read_json)
alldata <- lapply(alljsons, each_json)
alldata <- rbindlist(alldata, idcol = "filename")
alldata
#         filename           id conversion_px n_surfaces surface_id classification total_area_px total_area max_breadth max_length polygon_count scar_count percentage_detected_scars scar_contour.scar_id scar_contour.total_area_px scar_contour.total_area scar_contour.max_breadth scar_contour.max_length scar_contour.percentage_of_surface scar_contour.scar_angle scar_contour.polygon_count
#           <char>       <char>         <num>      <int>      <int>         <char>         <num>      <num>       <num>      <num>         <int>      <int>                     <num>                <int>                      <num>                   <num>                    <num>                   <num>                              <num>                  <char>                      <int>
#  1: ./file1.json rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          0        Ventral      530565.5      831.5        22.4       54.0             7          0                      0.00                   NA                         NA                      NA                       NA                      NA                                 NA                    <NA>                         NA
#  2: ./file1.json rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          1         Dorsal      530503.5      831.4        22.4       54.0             7          4                      0.62                    0                   129337.0                   202.7                     10.3                    41.7                               0.24                    1.85                          5
#  3: ./file1.json rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          1         Dorsal      530503.5      831.4        22.4       54.0             7          4                      0.62                    1                   100130.0                   156.9                      7.2                    43.0                               0.19                  357.36                          4
#  4: ./file1.json rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          1         Dorsal      530503.5      831.4        22.4       54.0             7          4                      0.62                    2                    93162.0                   146.0                      6.5                    41.4                               0.18                    5.01                          4
#  5: ./file1.json rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          1         Dorsal      530503.5      831.4        22.4       54.0             7          4                      0.62                    3                     6148.5                     9.6                      4.0                     7.1                               0.01                     NaN                          9
#  6: ./file1.json rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          2        Lateral      176204.0      276.2         8.6       54.2             3          2                      0.33                    0                    44605.0                    69.9                      5.0                    50.0                               0.25                     NaN                          3
#  7: ./file1.json rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          2        Lateral      176204.0      276.2         8.6       54.2             3          2                      0.33                    1                    12877.0                    20.2                      1.5                    22.3                               0.07                     NaN                          2
#  8: ./file1.json rub_al_khali    0.03958828          4          3       Platform       55252.5       86.6        20.3        6.6             5          1                      0.42                    0                    23298.5                    36.5                     15.0                     4.1                               0.42                     NaN                          4
#  9: ./file2.json          160    0.06443299          3          0         Dorsal      147674.0      613.1        21.5       36.1             5         10                      0.81                    0                    37128.0                   154.1                     10.1                    26.4                               0.25                  169.05                          9
# 10: ./file2.json          160    0.06443299          3          0         Dorsal      147674.0      613.1        21.5       36.1             5         10                      0.81                    1                    25267.5                   104.9                      6.6                    24.7                               0.17                  343.61                          6
# ---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
# 44: ./file3.json          194    0.12406948          3          1         Dorsal       65223.5     1004.0        38.7       33.6             8         13                      0.72                    8                     1684.5                    25.9                      9.8                     8.8                               0.03                     NaN                          9
# 45: ./file3.json          194    0.12406948          3          1         Dorsal       65223.5     1004.0        38.7       33.6             8         13                      0.72                    9                      862.0                    13.3                      3.3                     6.5                               0.01                     NaN                          5
# 46: ./file3.json          194    0.12406948          3          1         Dorsal       65223.5     1004.0        38.7       33.6             8         13                      0.72                   10                      827.5                    12.7                      6.3                     4.0                               0.01                     NaN                          5
# 47: ./file3.json          194    0.12406948          3          1         Dorsal       65223.5     1004.0        38.7       33.6             8         13                      0.72                   11                      787.0                    12.1                      4.0                     4.8                               0.01                     NaN                          6
# 48: ./file3.json          194    0.12406948          3          1         Dorsal       65223.5     1004.0        38.7       33.6             8         13                      0.72                   12                      699.5                    10.8                      4.0                     4.2                               0.01                     NaN                          6
# 49: ./file3.json          194    0.12406948          3          2        Lateral       15128.0      232.9        10.0       33.9             7          5                      0.69                    0                     6122.0                    94.2                      6.5                    28.7                               0.40                     NaN                          7
# 50: ./file3.json          194    0.12406948          3          2        Lateral       15128.0      232.9        10.0       33.9             7          5                      0.69                    1                     1477.0                    22.7                      1.9                    20.6                               0.10                     NaN                          3
# 51: ./file3.json          194    0.12406948          3          2        Lateral       15128.0      232.9        10.0       33.9             7          5                      0.69                    2                     1415.0                    21.8                      3.1                    13.6                               0.09                     NaN                          5
# 52: ./file3.json          194    0.12406948          3          2        Lateral       15128.0      232.9        10.0       33.9             7          5                      0.69                    3                      800.0                    12.3                      4.5                     6.6                               0.05                     NaN                          7
# 53: ./file3.json          194    0.12406948          3          2        Lateral       15128.0      232.9        10.0       33.9             7          5                      0.69                    4                      596.0                     9.2                      2.1                     9.7                               0.04                     NaN                          6
```

FYI: I use `data.table::rbindlist` twice here, you can also switch to `dplyr::bind_rows` (changing `idcol=` to `.id=`) for the same effect. If the number of columns were always identical (they are not), then one can get away with `do.call(rbind, liths)` and similar, but since some of the `lithic_contours` have no `scar_contours`, it takes a bit more work. If you cannot use `data.table` or `dplyr`, one can fashion an `rbind`-workflow that accounts for these: find the missing columns, add them with `NA` values, and ensure all frames have the same column-order.

Also, I'm using `jsonlite::read_json`, but I believe `rjson` is compatible-enough that it should be a drop-in replacement. YMMV, though hopefully it does not vary :-)

Comment: @ r2evans Cool! Thank you for this. It's definitely in a format that I am more used to working with. I'm assuming that the large amount of repeat rows are 'filler' caused by the unequal amount of row lengths stored as lists within the JSON files? I'm finding it very difficult to transfer data analysis on a straightforward tabular data set to working with lists and JSON files. Thank you for all your help and patience!

Comment: Yes, data is repeated to fill across the rows. If that is a surprise to you, then how else were you expecting it?

Comment: @ r2evans. Not a surprise, just clarifying. Thanks again